# How to dynamic setting sql_mode for mysql in SpringBoot program?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to set the `sql_mode` by using java , not execute the sql below

```
set @@sql_mode =‘STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION‘;
```

Answer (score 3):

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?sessionVariables=sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES